# Why Paypal standard button checkout on sandbox gets stuck on an unknown page

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

[image]
I get stuck on this page after logging in with sandbox personal account. I am using a Standard button for a subscription payment. Any ideas on what is happening?

Comment: create a personal sandbox account. Don't use the facilitator's account; test and see.

Comment: Hey what you have done to solve this issue???? Is this resolved

Comment: Yes. The problem was that rules in india does not allow using paypal to receive money from indian customers. So when we use a indian buyer account with indian seller account in paypal sandbox, we will meet this dead end. Since, there was no useful error messages, i couldn't figure this out right away.